# Determine whether a string is "empty"

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a JavaScript function to tell me whether a string object is empty. By "empty", I mean that it's not all just whitespace characters. I've written this prototype:

```
String.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
  return this.length === 0 || this === " " || this.test(/^\s*$/);
}
```

Is this alright?

Is there a more-performant version of this out there?

Comment: Your `this === " "` test will always be false since `this` is a `String` object, not a native string and will, therefore, never be "strictly equal" to `" "`.

Comment: How do you consider the string `"\0"`?

Comment: @Matthew: Aren't all native string basically String objects? Anyway, I tested it in firefox: `String.prototype.foo=function(){return(this==" ")};" ".foo()` <-- works (at least in firefox)!

Comment: @slebetman: Not quite. In some cases you can pretend that they are because the functions in `String.prototype` are available in strings. But when you call them, it's equivalent to `new String(s).method()`. The same thing happens with numbers. The reason your `this == " "` example works is because you used `==` instead of `===`. In that case, `this` will automatically be converted to a native string, so they are equal. With `===`, the types have to be the same, and `typeof this` is *always* "object".

Comment: I checked with Safari, and strictly comparing a `String` object with a constant string that contains the same character doesn't return `TRUE`.

Comment: Consider implementing an easier to understand solution, Ie a trim function

Answer (score 12):

Use

```
String.prototype.isEmpty = function() {  
  if (!this.match(/\S/)) {
    return ('enter some valid input.Empty space is not allowed');
  } else {
   return "correct input";
  }
}


alert("test 1:"+("    ".isEmpty()));
alert("test 2:"+("   \t ".isEmpty()));
alert("test 3:"+("  \n   ".isEmpty()));
alert("test 4:"+("hi".isEmpty()));
```

Note:

\s will match a whitespace character: space, tab or new line.

\S will match non whitespace character:anything but not a space, tab or new line.
If your string has a single character which is not a space, tab or new line, then it's not empty.
Therefore you just need to search for one character: \S

Comment: This is not a good answer. You have not addressed performance at all. You basically came up with a worse version of my implementation (if it were corrected with Mathew Crumley's feedback). For example, does using regular expressions over checking the length of the object's property cause a performance penalty?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you need to use `/^\s*$/.test(this)` instead of `this.test(/^\s*$/)`. There is no `test()` method for [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), unless you're using some JavaScript library that implements this method.

The `/^\s*$/.test(this)` would have been enough, but the first two expressions would short circuit if any one of them evaluates to true, without having to test the regular expression. That should be pretty efficient.

As [@Matthew Crumley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2214/matthew-crumley) noted in a comment above, your `this === " "` expression will always evaluate to false. You could remove this expression, or use `==` if you would will be expecting a lot of strings with just a single space character:

```
String.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
  return this.length === 0 || this == " " || /^\s*$/.test(this);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to check if `this.length` is strictly equal to 0. Are there any valid value for `this.length` that could be equal to 0, without to be 0?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: You're right. But in general using strict equals `===` wherever possible is considered a best practice amongst many JavaScript developers. And I guess there is no harm in that.

Comment: Generally speaking there could be harm in using the `===` operator in at least a case.

Answer (score 1):

```
String.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
  return this.length == 0 || /^\s*$/.test(this);
}
```

There is just a possibility out of 255 (not considering Unicode characters with code greater than 255) that a string with length 1 contains the space character. Considering strings with lenght greater than 1, the possibility get even lower.

Comment: I'd like to challenge that probability. Why 1/255? First, you are assuming 255 characters, when in fact there are quite a bit more. Next, you assume the same probability for each character, as if you pick one at random. A space is *probably* the most common character in a block of text, and it may be very common as a single letter in the OP's scenario.

Comment: @Kobi: I didn't speak of probability. I am not then sure the string made of just a space is the most probable string passed to a JavaScript function; if the JavaScript code is handling the username inserted from a user in a form, a string made of a single space is probably the less probable input.

Comment: What kiamlaluno is talking about is the omission of the original poster's explicit test for a string containing a single space. I agree that it is unnecessary.

Comment: @Mark Thomas: I was referring to that; thank you for clarifying what I was trying to say. `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

Generally, using `RegExp.prototype.test` for checking for a pattern match **without** compilation of a return array of matches (`String.prototype.match`) likely has a better performance. I'd try -- but haven't tested yet -- something like:

```
function isEmpty() {

     var string = arguments[0] ;
     var EMPTY_STRING_PATTERN = /^\s*$/ , empty = false ;

     if( EMPTY_STRING_PATTERN.exec(string) === true ) empty = true ;

     return empty ;

}
```

On a side note, it is considered bad practice to fiddle with the prototype object of core javascript objects.

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled with some of the things:

- I'm returning the inverse of this.length, for 0 that is `true`, for everything other number that is `false`.
- I removed the check for `" "`. I actually haven't seen much, if any cases where a single space was entered, removing the check is IMO faster on average.
- And flipped the regex <-> string like the others did.

`String.prototype.isEmpty = function() {`
`return !this.length || /^\s*$/.test(this);`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

from example https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

```
var orig="   foo  "
document.write(orig.trim())  // foo

document.write(orig.trim().length) // 3
```

tested on FF 3.6.8, Safari 5.0.1, Google Chrome 5.0.375.127, but produce js error on IE 8

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as [Daniel Vassallo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/222908/daniel-vassallo) originally provided, in example form.

```
String.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
    return /^\s*$/.test(this);
}
```

```js
document.body.style="background-color:black; color:green;font-size:12pt;font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;font-weight: bold";
String.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
     return /^\s*$/.test(this);
}
let test0 = ''.isEmpty();
let test1 = '\xa0'.isEmpty();
let test2 = ' '.isEmpty();
let test3 = '\t'.isEmpty();
let test4 = '\n'.isEmpty();
let test5 = '\n\n'.isEmpty();
let test6 = '\n\t\n'.isEmpty();
let test7 = '\r\n'.isEmpty();
let test8 = '\r\t\n'.isEmpty();
let test9 = '\r\n\t'.isEmpty();

var texts = new Array(
     ("String.prototype.isEmpty = function() {"), 
     ("     return /^\s*$/.test(this);"), 
     ("}"), 
     (""), 
     ("let test0 = ''.isEmpty()       // " + test1), 
     ("let test1 = ' '.isEmpty()      // " + test2) + " (non breaking space)", 
     ("let test2 = ' '.isEmpty()      // " + test2), 
     ("let test3 = '\\t'.isEmpty()     // " + test3), 
     ("let test4 = '\\n'.isEmpty()     // " + test4), 
     ("let test5 = '\\n\\n'.isEmpty()   // " + test5), 
     ("let test6 = '\\n\\t\\n'.isEmpty() // " + test6), 
     ("let test7 = '\\r\\n'.isEmpty()   // " + test7), 
     ("let test8 = '\\r\\t\\n'.isEmpty() // " + test8),
     ("let test9 = '\\r\\n\\t'.isEmpty() // " + test9)
);
texts.forEach(text => {
  let nobreakchar = '\xa0'
  ;
  document.body.append(document.createTextNode(text.replaceAll(" ",nobreakchar)))
  document.body.append(document.createElement("br"))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing more number of lines let's finish it in 2 lines only.

```
String.prototype.isEmpty = function () {
    return this.length === 0 || this.trim() === ""
}
```

With trim() you don't need to worry about if the variable is only having space characters and that is how you can avoid those falling in regex